# Cannot delete Azure Web App that has no resource group

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I was trying move some Azure web apps (Windows) that I have from North EU to West EU. Since this is not possible out of the box, I thought I would use the "Clone App" feature.

- I cloned "AppA" on The North EU Plan to "AppA-Temp" on West EU Plan, then deleted AppA and tried to clone "AppA-Temp" to "AppA" on the West EU Plan.

I got an error that "AppA" already exists in resource group. I checked the group, no "AppA" there. "AppA" was already deleted.

- I tried to clone AppA-Temp to AppA again, but this time I created a new resource group. I didn't get the error, the AppA was up (I can browse the service). However, deployment was in progress after more than 1 hour. I couldn't see AppA in resource list, so I can't manage it (even though it is running).
- So I tried to cancel deployment. The deployment is cancelled, the app is still running. It is not listed under resources, but listed under Apps in the App Service Plan and listed **without a resource group name**.

I tried with Rest API, Power Shell and nothing worked.
The following command returns no result.

`Get-AzureRmWebApp`

However I get result from the following

```
$plan = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name MyPlanName
$apps = Get-AzureRmWebApp -AppServicePlan $plan
```

When I try to delete the webapp by running

```
Remove-AzureRmWebApp -WebApp $apps[0]
```

I get error: `Remove-AzureRmWebApp : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NoContent'`
The app seems to have empty resource group in PowerShell and on Azure portal.

So I thought since I can't fix this, may be Microsoft Support can fix it. Since I didn't have a support plan, I bought a Dev Support plan subscription and paid 29 USD (I got message from my bank that the payment was successful). My support plan was not upgraded, I still can't delete the app and I was trying move some web apps I have from North EU to West EU. Since this is not possible out of the box, I thought I would use the "Clone App" feature.

- I cloned "AppA" on The North EU Plan to "AppA-Temp" on West EU Plan, then deleted AppA and tried to clone "AppA-Temp" to "AppA" on the West EU Plan.

I got an error that "AppA" already exists in resource group. I checked the group, no "AppA" there. "AppA" was already deleted.

- I tried to clone AppA-Temp to AppA again, but this time I created a new resource group. I didn't get the error, the AppA was up (I can browse the service). However, deployment was in progress after more than 1 hour. I couldn't see AppA in resource list, so I can't manage it (even though it is running).
- So I tried to cancel deployment. The deployment is cancelled, the app is still running. It is not listed under resources, but listed under Apps in the App Service Plan and listed **without a resource group name**.

I tried with Rest API, Power Shell and nothing worked.
The following command returns no result.

`Get-AzureRmWebApp`

However I get result from the following

```
$plan = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name MyPlanName
$apps = Get-AzureRmWebApp -AppServicePlan $plan
When I try to delete the webapp by running
Remove-AzureRmWebApp -WebApp $apps[0]
```

I get error: `Remove-AzureRmWebApp : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NoContent'`
The app seems to have empty resource group in PowerShell

So I thought since I can't fix this, may be Microsoft Support can fix it. Since I didn't have a support plan, I bought a Dev Support plan subscription and paid 29 USD (I got message from my bank that the payment was successful). My support plan was not upgraded, I still can't open a support ticket AND I am down 29 USD.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Open a billing support ticket about your support plan, they are free, to get them to fix that, then open a technical support issue. This problem looks to be backend issues that they will need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end the support plan was upgraded, I got in contact with support team. The Microsoft support employee had to forward my case to Azure internal team because she couldn't fix it. Few days later the issue was fixed.